# How to compare the highest value between different objects for each property and update the heights value?

Tags: javascript

I'm running a loop over data per row, each row the data can like so, I also have a var that stores the object with the highest value.

```
{"num":10,"num2":300}
{"num":50}
{"num":300,"num2":500, "num3": 75}
{"num":1,"num2":50}
```

I want to be able to get the highest value, so my results would be and I can update my var.

```
{"num":300,"num2":500, "num3": 75}
```

So I have one var that compares the keys if they match and the value is higher update it if not do nothing.

UPDATED,

Yes I have one object "max"

```
{"num":10,"num2":300}
```

and then I have another object "input"

```
{"num":300,"num2":500, "num3": 75}
```

I need to compare the first object max with input and match key properties to each other (num2) once matched if the input is higher update it and or if there is no match for example num3 is new save that one as well

I have the following

```
 let filtered = Object.keys(input)
   .filter(key => {
     if (key.includes("date")) return false;
     return !isNaN(input[key]);
   }).reduce((output, key) => {
     output[key] = input[key];
     return output;
   }, {});
```

This gives me the fist object I now need to compare it with the second object input and update everything.

Comment: Your not new to SO, show us what you tried

Comment: could you please add more information, you need the max value of what exactly ? of same keys inside different objects ?

Comment: Updated, check the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```js
let data = [
  {"num":10,"num2":300},
  {"num":50},
  {"num":300,"num2":500, "num3": 75},
  {"num":1,"num2":50}
]

let filtered = Object.keys(input)
 .filter(key => {
   if (key.includes("date")) return false;
   return !isNaN(input[key]);
 }).reduce((output, key) => {
    Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const highest = output[key]; 
    if (highest === undefined || highest < value) {
      output[key] = value
    }
  })
   return output;
 }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

UPDATE

```js
let output = {}
let firstInput = {"num":10,"num2":300}
let secondInput = {"num":0,"num2":0}
let thirdInput = {"num":11,"num2":301}

function fun(input, output){
  Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
    if ( 
      (output !== undefined && output[key] === undefined) ||
      output[key] < input[key]
    ) {
      output[key] = input[key]
    }
  });
  return output
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))

output = fun(firstInput, output)

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))

output = fun(secondInput, output)

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))

output = fun(thirdInput, output)

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Comment: It's not an array of objects.

Comment: @AlmogKoren what is the type?

Comment: I update the question again, as I didn't explain it well. But I have one object 
filtred = {"num":10,"num2":300} 

and then another object which I compare it to

Comment: @AlmogKoren added snippet according to changes on your post

Comment: Still a bit wrong or not working. 
I have input data, an object  - {"num":10,"num2":300}

which I want to compare with my max data, an object - {"num":0,"num2":0},

I want the comparison to match the object key between the two and do a check for the highest number so I can update max data and run the check again. 

also if there is no match, for example, max object has num4 or var4 i.e. that is new key it should grab the key as well, so that is there for the next comparison

Comment: @AlmogKoren Could you please check last update and let me know if it works for you

Comment: That is better, but for someone reason when num2 is NaN or null it's missing in the final output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204495/discussion-between-matvii-hodovaniuk-and-almog-koren).

Answer (score 1):

By using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), wrapped inside a function which accepts the name of the property.

```js
var arr = [
  {"num": 10, "num2": 300},
  {"num": 50},
  {"num": 300,"num2": 500,"num3": 75},
  {"num": 1,"num2": 50}
];

function getMax(prop) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(o => !isNaN(o[prop]) && o[prop]));
}

console.log(getMax("num"));
```

For getting a max on number of properties, modify the method slightly to the below... first store the max of each property, then get the final max.

```js
var arr = [
  {"num": 10, "num2": 300},
  {"num": 50},
  {"num": 300, "num2": 500, "num3": 75 },
  {"num": 1, "num2": 50}
];

function getMax(props) {
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    values.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(o => !isNaN(o[props[i]]) && 
o[props[i]])));
  }
  return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
}

console.log(getMax(["num", "num2"]));
```

Comment: The name of the property can by anything, and there can be unlimited properties

Comment: I don't think you understand, it can be num or next data it can be called row

Comment: @AlmogKoren No, you explained your problem really poorly. Seeing the update it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this, right?

```
const rowData1 = {a: 10, 'b': 100};
const rowData2 = {a: 11};

const rows = [
  rowData1,
  rowData2
];

// Output {a: 11, b: 100 }
rows.reduce((highestValues, rowData) => {
  Object.entries(rowData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const highest = highestValues[key]; 
    if (highest === undefined || highest < value) {
      // Not assigned yet or smaller
      highestValues[key] = value
    }
  })
  return highestValues
}, {});
```